# Encoding just arabic part in Url Not all Url

Tags: php, urlencode, url-encoding

I have this link: [http://www.example.com?p=عنوان](http://www.example.com?p=%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86) مقال اخبار

I want to encode url without damage it so I need to urlencoding arabic part form url => "عنوان مقال اخبار" NOT all url

Example:

url will become after encoding

```
http://www.example.com?p=%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1
```

NOT

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3Fp%3D%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1
```

Hint: I got this such link from RSS NOT built from my side.

also, I do not want to split the url and encode the arabic part then join it again. i want general solution to all expected url, such as www.example.com/عربي/123
www.example.com/123/عربي/عربي

Comment: Well, the solution *is* to split/parse the URL, encode the parts individually, and join them back together again. Why is this not an option?

Comment: because i have many url structures as I mentioned in question above.

Comment: www.example.com/عربي/123 www.example.com/123/عربي/عربي

Comment: And why is that a reason not to do it this way? *Parse* the URL (there's a function for that), *split* the path, *url encode* each part, then just put it all back together again.

Comment: I have hundreds of urls so i need to check every url alone, what about if website change its url structure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com?p=عنوان مقال اخبار';

$foo = preg_replace_callback(
    '/([\x{0600}-\x{06ff}]|[\x{0750}-\x{077f}]|[\x{fb50}-\x{fc3f}]|[\x{fe70}-\x{fefc}])+/Uui'
    ,(function($match) { return urlencode($match[1]); })
    ,$url
);

echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

@deceze's answer is the most correct one. He was suggesting that you...

- Break apart the URL with [parse_url](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).
- Split the path by `/`.
- Call `urlencode` on everything.
- Put the URL back together.

That will make sure you produce a valid URL.

However, if you don't care about validation, something like the below will work:

```
function EncodeExistingURL($input) {

    //From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters
    //The percent sign is included to leave existing encoded characters intact.
    $valid  = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_.~!*\'();:@&=+$,/?#[]%';
    $length = strlen($input);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $character = $input[$i];
        $output   .= (strpos($valid, $character) === FALSE ? rawurlencode($character) : $character); 
    }
    return $output;

}
```